# Glassfish on numproc restricted server

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, glassfish, centos, server

I have a virtual server at german provider 1&1.

They limit the number of threads/processes (the value called numproc in cat /proc/user_beancounters) to 128. Unfortunately, it is nearly impossible to out of the box run a glassfish on that server.

My question is simple: Is there any way to tell glassfish, that it should not use more then ~100 threads???

Thanks in advance for your help, any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone should ever have the same problem: I solved it.

The key to this is "max thread pool size", which can be configured in the glassfish admin console.